# Wordpress site with multi-language functionality

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I don't know if there is a sub-stackoverflow page for asking Wordpress questions, sorry if I'm doing it wrong now.

I want to develop a multi-language website wherein certain pages **do** exist for a language, and wherein some languages **don't** have the page.

ENG:
`www.site.com/*EN*/services`

NL:
`www.site.com/*NL*/services --> 404 not found - because we don't deliver services in NL..`

What's the best workaround for this? --> I've looked up multi-language plugins, lots of possibilities...

Thanks for reading and responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements it sounds like [WPML](https://wpml.org/) is the best solution for you. I have used it many times. It provides the exact functionality you are looking for.

https://wpml.org/

Comment: Thanks, Is the free version also an option? Or do I need to pay for the plugin?

Comment: It is not free but I think the base version may work for you.